# How to pass down custom props on initial render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, ecmascript-2016

I think it might be silly question to ask but trust me I didn't find an answer . I am passing down data via props to children component but I am stuck and getting error . Normally, I am passing data on form submit ( I mean when user type something and do click on submit ) I am showing data it in child component via props but on initial render of an application I am getting error `props is undefined` . Actually I have knowledge about `defaultProps` but I think it might be possible in class base component . I want to do something like `defaultProps` in functional Component , I am stuck could someone please help me to achieve my goal .

**Code**

```
 import React from "react";

const ViewCourse = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.courses.map(newData => (
        <div>{newData.title}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ViewCourse;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `classname.defaultProps` to assign the initial value. Also to access props in functional component, you will have to pass it as an argument.

```js
import React from "react";

const ViewCourse = (props) => (
  <div>
    {props.courses.map(newData => (
      <div>{newData.title}</div>
    ))}
  </div>
);

export default ViewCourse;

ViewCourse.defaultProps = {
  courses: [],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using function component. You've to get props in the argument.

```
const ViewCourse = (props) => {
  // use props here.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In functional component *props* is the argument.

```
import React from "react";

const ViewCourse = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.courses.map(newData => (
        <div>{newData.title}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ViewCourse;
```